# phpexcel fit to selection

Tags: phpexcel

I generate an excel file using the great PHPExcel library. At this moment I need to show all the columns into a single page. You know the feeling when you have to scroll left and right up and down to see all the data. Basically I have 33 columns and I need to fit them on any display

I don't know if is my setup or where is the problem, but I can't make it work. This is the code I'm using

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToPage(true);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);
```

On MS Excel I select all thw colums then I choose View-> Zoom, then select Fit Selection. How can I do that programatically when excel file is generated with PHPExcel.

Comment: Fit to page is actually related to Excel print option, as are all the pageSetup properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i hope i don't understand you wrong, here it goes:
phpExcel has an method called setZoomScalezoom(), however this does not auto fill the whole screen:

```
example:
$excel = new PHPExcel();

$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(300);

$writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($excel);
$writer->save('test.xls');
```

got my information from:
source: http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/phpexcel_library/1.7.4/view/5/4/

> Setting worksheet zoom level To set a worksheet’s zoom level, the
>   following code can be used:
>
> $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getSheetView()->setZoomScale(75);
>
> Note that zoom level should be in range 10 – 400.

Comment: There is no way that you can set this to work perfectly on all screens because you cannot know (in advance) what screen size the spreadsheet will be displayed in. All you can do is provide a suggestion through this value; but it's up to the user running MS Excel to "tune" the zoom level to suit their own screen; so this is answer is the best you can get.